How to integrate Oracle Column Comments into LangChain for enhanced SQL query generation (NL2SQL)?
I'm working with an Oracle database that uses column comments to detail cryptic column names, crucial for data retrieval operations. These comments are visible in Oracle SQL Developer but are not included in the CREATE table statement:
COMMENT ON COLUMN "SCHEMA"."TABLE_NAME"."CLMN_NM" IS 'Column which contains information X. Distinct values: ("A", "B", "C")';

I'm using LangChain to interface with the database. LangChain internally requests the CREATE statement. But since the column comments are after the create statement, LangChain does not have access to it.
How can I modify my approach so that LangChain can dynamically read and utilize these Oracle column comments? The goal is for LangChain to programmatically use these comments to better determine which columns to select for generating accurate SQL queries in natural language processing contexts.
Here's my current setup:
from cx_Oracle import makedsn
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase 
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent 
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import SQLDatabaseToolkit

dsn_tns = makedsn(host=host, port=port, service_name=service_name)
connection_string = f"oracle+cx_oracle://{usr}:{pwd}@{dsn_tns}"
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(connection_string)

toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db,llm=chat_client)
agent_executor = create_sql_agent(llm=chat_client, toolkit=toolkit, agent_type="openai-tools")
agent_executor.invoke("How many orders from Singapore did we have in March 2023?")

I'm looking for guidance on modifying my code so that LangChain gets access to the column comments.

I don't know your langchain product's capabilities. But if you can execute a SQL statement, you can query the data dictionary. So simply query:
select * from all_tab_comments where owner = 'MYSCHEMA' AND table_name = 'MYTABLE' -- table level comments
select * from all_col_comments where owner = 'MYSCHEMA' AND table_name = 'MYTABLE' -- column level comments

Thank you, Paul, for your response. Your suggestion to query the data dictionary is correct for manual SQL operations, and I appreciate your input. However, my challenge is integrating this data automatically into LangChain via my Python setup. I am specifically looking for guidance on how to modify my code to feed this column comment information into LangChain dynamically.

@DataJanitor, this doesn't need to be "manual" - I mean integrating a query into your code and obtaining the columns programmatically. You can then map them to whatever object you need locally, whatever makes sense for your program. If your environment lets you issue queries and is a real programming environment, this is an option, may be the only option if your API hasn't encapsulated this for you. If it has provided an encapsulation, great, but under the covers it'd have to be doing this precise query on your behalf, or invoking another layer (like dbms_metadata) that does so.
